# how do I assign names to colours?

Tags: python

I can't find out what is wrong with my code, I am trying to assign the following names to the corresponding colours in the given order:

```
name = ["raymond", "patrick", "Dominique"]
colours = ["green", "yellow", "red"]

for name, colour in zip(name, colours): 
    print(name, "-->", colours[I])
```

The output that I get looks like this:

```
raymond --> ['green', 'yellow', 'red']
patrick --> ['green', 'yellow', 'red']
Dominique --> ['green', 'yellow', 'red']
```

I am working with Python

Comment: What is the variable `I`?

Comment: `zip` already iterates on **elements** from both lists so you can just do `print(name, "-->",  colour)`. BTW how can you get this output? This code throws a `NameError`

Comment: Can you post the exact output? That code doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

You dont have the index `I`

the code should be:

```
names = ["raymond", "patrick", "Dominique"]
colours = ["green", "yellow", "red"]

for name, colour in zip(names, colours):
    print(name, "-->", colour)
```

Which outputs:

```
raymond --> green
patrick --> yellow
Dominique --> red
```

Comment: It's worth noting that while in this particular case reusing the name `name` does not cause any problem, in general it should be discouraged.

Comment: HI David, that is not the output that I get when I type in your code. I still get the same output as mine when I type it in

Comment: @PatrickChong this is odd. Is what you posted on your question is the entire code used?

Answer (score 0):

You can use an index to access both array

```
for i in range(len(name)): 
    print(name[i], "-->", colours[i])
```

---

Or build `zip` that pairs lists `zip(name, colours) => [('raymon', 'green'), ('patrick', 'yellow'), ('Dominique', 'red')]`

```
for n, c in zip(name, colours):
    print(n, "-->", c)
```

Comment: HI Azro, is there any way to use my code, rather than pairing? To get the output :

Comment: @PatrickChong My first code is from yours but with fixing the errors, the 2nd use pairing, so what about the first ?